# How to convert this SQL statement into Python: MID? SUBSTRING?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, substring

I am trying to filter a Python DataFrame by substring. It is very simple and straightforward to do this in SQL, but I have had great difficulty translating this logic into Python code.

This is the SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM [oe.data.0.Current]
WHERE  substring([series_id],5,2) = '50'
OR substring([series_id],5,5) = '72400';
```

So essentially I want to filter the 'series_id' column by specific character values in the 5th and 6th character position and the 5th through 9th character position.

I don't understand how MID or SUBSTRING translates into DataFrames.

How do I acheive the results of this SQL query in a DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map it and use lambda function:

```
df[df['series_id'].map(lambda x: x[4:6]=='50' or x[4:9]=='72400')]
```

There might be a better solution, but this is what I use in similar cases.

**edit**

I found out there is another solution, which looks cleaner to me, if nothing else. Pandas actually has some built-in functions for working with series of string:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

In your case I think that either the contains function - combined with regular expression, or the slice function would work well. Example:

```
df[(
    (df['series_id'].str.slice(4,5)=='50') |
    (df['series_id'].str.slice(4,9)=='72400')
)]
```

or with contains:

```
df[df['series_id'].str.contains(r'.{4}((50)|(72400))')]
```

Comment: good idea! but you have to correct slicing indices: `df[df['series_id'].map(lambda x: x[4:6]=='50' or x[4:9]=='72400')]`